# Discord.py erro no comando calcular

Tags: python, syntax-error, comandos

Tenho um comando de calculadora com botões, e o comando parece que está tudo bem, porém quando eu inicio o comando, eu recebo esse erro:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Meu código:

```
def calculator(self, exp):
        o = exp.replace('x', '*')
        o = o.replace('÷', '/')
        result = ''
        try:
            result=str(eval(o))
        except:
            result='Ocorreu um erro.'
        return result

    @commands.command()
    async def calcular(self, ctx):
        m = await ctx.send(content='Carregando calculadora...')
        expression='None'
        delta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        e = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}\"s | {ctx.author.id}", description=expression, timestamp=delta)
        await m.edit(components=Button, embed=e)
        while m.created_at < delta:
            res = await bot.wait_for('button_click')
            if res.author.id == int(res.message.embeds[0].title.split('|')([1])) and res.message.embeds[0].timestamp < delta:
                expression = res.message.embeds[0].description
                if expression == 'None' or expression == 'Ocorreu um erro.':
                    expression = ''
                if res.component.label == 'Exit':
                    await res.respond(content='Calculadora fechada.', type=7)
                    break
                elif res.component.label == '←':
                    expression = expression[:-1]
                elif res.component.label == "Clear":
                    expression=None
                elif res.component.label == "=":
                    expression = self.calculator(expression)
                else:
                    expression += res.component.label
                f=discord.Embed(title=f"{res.author.name}\"s calculator|{res.author.id}", description=expression, timestamp=delta)
                await res.respond(content='', embed=f, component=Button, type=7)
```

Se alguém puder ajudar a resolver esse erro, serei grato.

Answer (score 0):

Muda alguma coisa se trocar:

```
result=str(eval(o))
```

por isso aqui:

```
result=int(str(eval(o)))
```

?

Comment: deu esse erro: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable